# Continuous functions on non-compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Suppose we have a non-compact subset of $E \subset R$. Now, I am trying to find examples of:

1. $f: E \rightarrow R$, which is not bounded. I think that since $E$ is not compact, then $f(x) = x$ should not be bounded and should work in this case.
2. $f: E \rightarrow R$, which is bounded but has no max, min value. In this case I have an example like:

Take E = $(0,1)$, then (1-x)$sin\frac{1}{x}$ will be bounded, but obviously won't have max/min values.

My question is my reasoning behind 1 correct. And How to generalize 2.

Comment: When you say "which is not bounded" in part $1$, are you referring to $E$ or $f$?

Answer (score 2):

Sketch (for $1$.): Suppose that $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.  Since compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and bounded, $E$ is either not closed or not bounded.

Suppose that we're looking for an unbounded function.

- If $E$ is not bounded, then you are correct that $f(x)=x$ is an unbounded function.
- If $E$ is bounded, then it is not closed, so there exists a limit point $a$ of $E$ not contained in $E$.  The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x-a|}$ is unbounded in $E$ (the denominator is never zero since $a$ is not in $E$, but points in $E$ get arbitrarily close to $a$ since $a$ is a limit point).